# Ruby, how to change every "s" in each word of string, except if "s" is first letter

Tags: ruby

Trying to create a simple multi-word string method that replaces some of the letters of a string (3 for "e", 0 for "o", 1 for "I", and "z" for "s" (unless "s" is first letter in word. So, "sons sams roses" will change to "sonz samz roz3z".

All of my specs pass except for not changing the first 's' of each word in a string. I can't seem to go from working with each letter in a string to each word, targeting the first letter.

```
class String
  def leetspeak
    word = self.split("")
    new_word = []

    word.each do |i|
      if i == "e"
        new_word.push(3)
      elsif i == "o"
        new_word.push(0)
      elsif i == "I"
        new_word.push(1)
      elsif (i == "s") && ((word.find_index(" ") + 1) != "s")
        new_word.push("z")
      else
        new_word.push(i)
      end
    end
    new_word.join
  end
end
```

On the last elsif, I thought I could target the first letter using .find_index(" ") + 1, but it doesn't work, and even if it did, it doesn't work for the very first letter in the string, if it was "s". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind to show a desired input/output? It is hard to understand, what is the rule for “s”.

Comment: *not changing the first 's' of each word* -- What does finding a space have to do with locating the first s in *each* word?

Comment: @mudasobwa: Final output should change submitted string, "sams roses Ivans are splashes" to "samz r0z3z 1vanz ar3 splazh3z" where the letters "e, o, I and s" are replaced with "3, 0, 1 and z" respectively, except for the first "s" of each word.

Comment: Your example does not nail down what you want to do.  I suggest you not ask questions until you've thought about the problem a little more carefully. A more helpful example would be to indicate what the output of "sss s loss" should be.  How the heck does your "roses" output fit your rule?

Comment: @7stud: Yes, it explains it, see first sentence "that replaces some of the letters of a string (3 for "e", 0 for "o", 1 for "I", and "z" for "s". User submits multi-word string, some letters are replaced, "s" replaces "z", except if "s" is first letter.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland: see top paragraph in question: ""sons sams roses" will change to "sonz samz roz3z"." That was added a while ago. And thanks for the tip for assigning examples of input/output. I shall do so from here on out.

Comment: This really sounds like homework or a tutorial question. If so, do you really want people to tell you how to do it instead of figuring it out yourself?

Comment: @the Tin Man: Yes, it is an exercise and I gave it multiple hours of effort. This is my 2nd attempt at it in the past week and I was not able to work past this one point on my own previously. What is frustrating is the status quo that developers assume that people don't learn when provided an answer. This is not the case. mrodrigues below provided a solution, reminding me of .gsub and also providing a Regex, that I have no idea how it works. But, I'm diligently studying Regex right now, at 12:30am. So, your assumption is incorrect. Along with assuming that I am able to figure it out alone.

Comment: @theTinMan - What's interesting is that many SO developers here assume that just because someone is seeking an answer that they are not learning. Assuming that noobs want to be spoon fed. Lazy. Neither is the case. You are doing nobody any favors by withholding knowledge when people have done due diligence in trying to figure it out themselves. If it were that easy...there would be no need for Stackoverflow. Good day to you sir. ...I said Good Day!

Comment: You make a number of assumptions about the people who use the site. There are very experienced professionals here who have had many discussions whether or not homework questions should even be allowed; In the past the answer was no, but there's a bit more relaxed attitude toward them now. But the general question that I asked remains and is often asked because it's an important one. As is, your question isn't clear as evidenced by the comments, yet you argue with those who are trying to help you.

Comment: @theTinMan - If you took but a moment to look, you will see that I did not argue with anyone, especially the answer that I accepted. I didn't argue with anyone and clarified the answer when prompted, and even accepted Cary Swoveland's advice on defining input/output, thanked him even. You, on the other hand, are not helping. I am making no assumptions, merely pointing out that you contribute to the prevailing perception that SO is not for beginners and is for elitists. I am not alone when it comes to this perception: https://goo.gl/axwa1j  Note top comment.

Comment: Padawan, if SO is not for beginners, how do you explain that you received five answers to your question, which is somewhat above average?  Your question is not particularly challenging for an experienced Rubiest, so why did they offer up their time to post a solution? To show off or for the rep? In some cases that may have been part of it, but it's mainly because they want to help others learn Ruby, just as they were helped here when they were new to it. If you find some people here can be a little abrupt or abrasive, or you disagree agree with them, that's life.

Comment: @Cory Swoverland - If you do not wish to accept the words of a beginner who has done due diligence in trying to find answers myself, [then maybe you will listen to others with more experience who voice the same issues](http://michael.richter.name/blogs/awhy-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow), like "it is the moderators who are ruining stackoverflow, not the site itself. they are fascists and they punish anyone who disagrees with their views, even when their views are not representative of the community they purport to serve." Or maybe Redditer developers goo.gl/axwa1j

Comment: Stack Overflow is moderated by the users who have earned the level to help manage the site. Some disagree with how the site is run but by common consensus of its users, who vote on the policies and rules, it's done this way. It's acknowledged by the owners of Stack Exchange and the users that some don't like how it works and those people are free to not like it. By creating an account and using the site, you agreed to the rules. Stack Overflow is for well thought out questions, no matter the experience of those asking. [meta] would be good for you to take further concerns or comments to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many ways to accomplish that. Do you require this implementation to be using if/else? Otherwise, here follows a simpler one:

```
def leetspeak
  self
    .gsub('e', '3')
    .gsub('o', '0')
    .gsub('I', '1')
    .gsub(/(?!^)s/, 'z')
end
```

The `/(?!^)s/` part is a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (or regex) that means *everything that's an `s` except if it's the first character*. The `(?!something)` is the [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and the `^` is the beginning of the string. The `gsub` method replaces globally (in the whole string) any substring which is matched by the expression, and replaces it with the second argument.

I'm sure that are better ways to do that, both in performance and in clarity, but I guess this implementation should be good enough.

UPDATE:

I had misread the question, I've fixed the regex to *not* match every first `s` in any word using the `\b`, which stands for [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
def leetspeak
  self
    .gsub('e', '3')
    .gsub('o', '0')
    .gsub('I', '1')
    .gsub(/(?!\b)s/, 'z')
end
```

Comment: Brilliant!! I love this answer! I didn't even think of gsub. And, no, it doesn't require if/else (but thank you for asking). And thanks for the regex, this is a good opportunity for me to study up on it some more. ..now to see if it'll work! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, but it only affects the very first "s" in the string, not the first "s" of each word, which was my original problem.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, fixed my answer to solve this problem.

Comment: Fantastic!!! Concise, simple and it even works!! All specs passed. Couldn't get any of the other guys' answers to pass. Now to dissect regex and study this witchcraft you flung at me. * does happy dance*

Comment: Hahaha, great! And good luck in your new journey through the magic world of regexes :D

Comment: You could replace the first three `gsubs` with [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr): `"fee fI foo fum".tr 'eoI', '301' #=> "f33 f1 f00 fum"`.

Comment: That's true, nice! :)
But I guess in this case I'd still prefer to use several `gsub`s for symmetry. Maybe store the replacements in a hash and map over them like you did. :)

Comment: A small thing: you don't need `self` or the first period. `gsub('e', '3').gsub('o', '0').gsub('I', '1').gsub(/(?!^)s/, 'z')` is enough. A more substantial concern: what if the replacements were `"e"=>"3", "3"=>"0"`? `"e"` would be replaced with `"0"`. Sequential replacements are fraught with peril (unless multiple replacements are intended, of course, but that's not the case here).

Comment: That's a good point, indeed. Fortunately in this case the domain was simple enough to allow sequential replacement, but in a more complex case I'd need to rethink my implementation. I guess I'd implement a `ReplacementBuilder` class which would build a regex with each rule being explicitly stated then apply it to the string, something like `replacement_builder.replace('e', '3').replace('3', '0).apply(self)`.

Comment: Oh, and I just used `self` for clarity, I prefer to be explicit than implicit, but that's debatable. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method.

```
class String
  def leetspeak
    word = self.split("")
    new_word = []

    word.each_with_index do |i, index|
      if i == "e"
        new_word.push(3)
      elsif i == "o"
        new_word.push(0)
      elsif i == "I"
        new_word.push(1)
      elsif (i == "s") && index != 0
        new_word.push("z")
      else
        new_word.push(i)
      end
    end
    new_word.join
  end
end

"ss".leetspeak
=> "sz"
```

you can invoke `leetspeak` method for each word:

```
"ss roses sams".split(" ").map{|e| e.leetspeak}.join(" ")
=> "sz r0z3z samz"
```

Comment: thanks, this is good, but this only resolves the very first "s" in the string. I need it to affect every first "s" of each word in the string, so "ss, roses sams" turns to "sz roz3z samz".

Comment: @Padawan It is easy, you just change your code a little: `"ss roses sams".split(" ").map{|e| e.leetspeak}.join(" ") => "sz r0z3z samz"`

Comment: Because your answer more closely matches the op's experience level, and it doesn't traverse the string multiple times, I am going to upvote your answer.

Comment: @7stud Thanks a lot, I am so happy we can understand each other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want but `word.find_index(" ")` returns an index and you should use the index like this:

```
elsif (i == "s") && ((word[word.find_index(" ") + 1]) != "s")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working in the code; the "s" in words aren't changing to "z". What I want is to submit a multi-word string and have this line change all the "s" to "z" except the first "s" of each word. So "suns roses sams" would be "sunz roses samz".

Answer (score 0):

My example:

```
str = "egad!, she repeated, it's VI o'clock\nI really must go!"
```

If I understand the correctly, here are a couple of ways that use the hash:

```
replacements = { "e"=>"3", "o"=>"0", "I"=>"1", "s"=>"z" }
```

and the regex:

```
r = /
    [a-rt-z] # match any lower case letter other than s
    |        # or
    (?<=\w)  # match a word character in a positive lookbehind
    s        # match s
    /ix      # case indifferent and extended mode
```

**#1**

```
str.gsub(r) { |s| replacements[s] || s }
  #=> "3gad!, sh3 r3p3at3d, it's V1 0'cl0ck\n1 r3ally muzt g0!"
```

**#2**

```
replacements.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }
str.gsub(r, replacements)
  #=> "3gad!, sh3 r3p3at3d, it's V1 0'cl0ck\n1 r3ally muzt g0!"
```

Comment: Thanks, am looking through this now.